# What does context mean by context-free and context-sensitive grammars?

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-sensitive-grammar

If I have something like `var string = "var";`, then after the first double quote the rules change, and the `var` does not mean the same thing as it means at the beginning of the text. After the second double quote things turn back to normal. How is that not considered context?

(Please don't use those arrows in your answer, try a natural language instead!)

Comment: Have you read [this Q/A](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42988/what-does-context-in-context-free-grammar-refer-to)? Seems to provide a full answer, and explains the arrows! The "context" of being text within quotes isn't the same definition of context that the terminology refers to, it's more like being in a different state in a state transition machine.

Comment: @hnefatl I still do not understand. Isn't there a simple explanation without "A"-s and "x"-s and arrows? I have a very simple example in the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of the arrow is important, so if I can't talk about it, it's going to be difficult to explain. So, sorry, I'm going to use arrows. They really aren't complicated.

The expression `A -> ...` means "an `A` is `...`". It does *not* mean "`...` is an `A`". Context-free means that if `A` can be "..." in some context, it can be "..." in any context. But the arrow always points from category to specific; never backwards.

In your example, an `identifier` is a letter followed by a bunch of alphanumeric symbols:

```
 identifier -> letter (letter OR digit)...
```

So `identifier` could be **var**. That doesn't mean that **var** is always an `identifier`, as your example shows. The arrow points in one direction.

Because the grammar is context-free, if when we are looking for an `identifier` in some context and we accept **var** as an `identifier`, then in any other context where we are looking for an `identifier`, we must also accept **var**.

But there are contexts (between quotes) where we are *not* looking for an `identifier`. That's fine; the context-free condition has not been broken. The context applies in the direction of the arrow.

Comment: If so, then how do you call the change/difference between "when we are looking for an identifier" and "we are not looking for an identifier"?

Comment: @inf3rno: I don't call it anything. We're looking for an identifier because we were looking for something larger, perhaps an expression, which includes an identifier. The expression also includes a `string literal`, which starts with a quote. When we encounter the quote, it becomes evident that the only way to continue does not include an identifier. "Context-free" is a technical term, like it or not, and it has a technical meaning. I attempted why the word "context" is used in that term but it could just as well have been called a "Type-2 grammar", with exactly the same definition.

Comment: I thought the topic has a more rich vocab. I can hardly believe that people are not talking about it, just writing symbols... Well I think the "we are looking for an identifier, which can be ...",  and the "we are looking for a text, which can be any symbol until we reach the second double qoute"  are 2 different contexts. The "identifier -> letter + alphanumeric*" is a rule. In context-free grammar we have a fixed rule set and every context can apply a subset of that. In context-sensitive grammar the same is true, but the rules can change by changing the context.

Comment: But if this is true I just don't understand why we make a difference. Why not just add another rule to the set instead of changing existing rules?

Comment: I think the "when we are looking for an identifier" part is unique in our rule set if we are talking about context-free grammar. This way the rule set does not depend on the context (it is context-free), while the rule we can apply from that rule set still depends on the context. In context-sensitive languages we can have a different rule set in each context. Or I totally misunderstood something a few comments earlier. :D

Comment: @inf3rno: when I get back home, I'll decide whether to try again or just delete this answer. Evidently, it's not helping provide you with an intuition and when I reread it, I thought it might too oversimplified for someone who is really trying to understand the theory.

Comment: Do you have an article or book where these terms are defined in a non math language?

Comment: Actually I just want to understand the basic model behind these grammars before writing an own parser to practice on a hobby project. But if it is that complicated, then I just write a simple parser with my own model. It will be slow and probably ugly too, but good for starting...

Comment: @inf3rno: it is not complicated. The fact that it uses mathematical logic and a couple of symbols does not necessarily make it more complicated than `2 + 2 = 4`. Explaining it is complicated only if I have to do it with one hand tied behind my back.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-context-mean-by-context-sensitive-grammar-in-simple-terms-no-arrows-cryptic-letters-etc/answer/Peter-Koves

Comment: I ended up watching the "Languages and Grammars" PPT here: https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/info2950_2011sp/syllabus-sp2011.htm These rules are very simple after you understand what a terminal and a non-terminal mean. I think they simply did not have a better word than "context" for those special rules. I don't think it has anything to do with the definition of context in natural languages. The only common thing that it comes prior to something.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question because the answers are more subtle than maybe people are giving credit for -- in my opinion, anyhow -- even if we agree to use the word "context" specifically in the technical formal-language sense.

The first answer is good, but from a certain perspective I could see someone feeling it's circular or begs the question (perhaps because the technical definition of "context free" itself is a little circular).  After all, why can't a parser look at the *second* `var` and "say", in effect: ok, here's a sequence that matches the identifier rule, let's call it an identifier which in this case happens to be inside a string literal (that's not impossible: consider a language where identifiers start with a **$** character and are parsed that way in string literals too, which eventually yields a value-substitution).

Sure, a grammar is context-free if all production rules can be stated without any contextual qualifications.  The `var string = "var";` example illustrates the point insofar as the rule matching the first `var` to an identifier (i.e., the pattern which generates an identifier in the modeled language) does not internally present any notion of context.

So, why can't a parser just start immediately before the *second* var and conclude that this second "var" string is also an identifier?  If we're thinking in terms of context, we'd say that the parsing sequence up to that point establishes a context where the identifier rule is temporarily suspended.  But that identifier rule does not have any way to declare which contexts it "belongs" to.

Presumably context-free rules do not *need* to describe or declare contexts where they are active because of how a parser would work through strings in the language.  In this case, a parser would never "get to" the position immediately before the second `var` because (for instance) it would match the entire quoted string with one rule, starting at the open quote.

So the answer to my earlier question would be that in a context-free grammar a parser *could*, indeed, read the second `var` as an identifier.  Except that it wouldn't, because it would never be in a state where it is trying to find rules to match that specific location in the input stream.

In other words, what might seem conceptually to be situations where context is relevant are formally accounted for by engineering rules such that locations where contexts might seem to be in effect are subsumed in larger matches -- they are never deciding factors (causing ambiguity) between two different potential rule-matches.  Two competing rules never "collide" in such a way that keeping track of context is necessary to resolve which rule applies.  This all relies on the fact that only certain positions in an input string will ever be sites where rules are tested -- others are just consumed by matches for a single rule.

Notice, however, that this is a specific notion of "parsing" based on parsers that scan input from beginning to end.  Consider, instead, something like a syntax highlighter that seeks to make an educated guess about the nature of each input character without fully parsing an entire source-code file (and all its `includes` or etc.).  For instance, an ideal highlighter for Qt/C++ source files (actually this doesn't happen even in Qt's own IDE) would color the `%` in (e.g.) `%2` differently as part of a **QString** (and also differently than the surrounding text which has no special meaning) than in an expression like `x%2` (testing whether **x** is even or odd).  A grammar to enable this would infer the meaning of a **%** even if it *started* a parsing process at a **%** character directly, rather than relying on rules to be coordinated so that -- in this case -- the string-literal **%** is always consumed as part of a string-literal rule.

Notice that a highlighter will, ideally, be reasonably accurate and help even while an input source is being modified, so that it might not be fully parseable in the first place.  If I open a new file and position the cursor somewhere, a highlighter could -- again, best-case scenario -- start to observe constructions around the cursor's current location, while perhaps a different thread also launches a formal parse from the start of the file.  We might want to analyze rules that are specific to the former case -- trying to process the "neighborhood" of some intermediate location in an input source (e.g., the current cursor location) via rules which cannot be assumed to match only in coordinated sequences from the input start.

In theory, that sort of "processing" of an input string involves a different notion of parsing, which would yield a different classification of grammars.  For instance, we could ask about languages with the property that each input character can be assigned a specific type or "catcode" in isolation, without considering its neighbors and without "parsing" up to that point -- i.e., scanners could run in parallel, selecting any individual character, if desired.  Imagine a language where identifiers (and only identifiers) use capital letters (and no other characters) whereas quoted strings only use lower-case letters (relying on unicode hex-numbers for any other symbols).  In this case one could distinguish identifiers from string literals even when taking one character at random.

Obviously such a language might be too simple for practical use -- but it illustrates the point that languages can be evaluated based on how easy or difficult it is to infer details about input strings (again, consider syntax-highlighting as a practical use-case) by examining the neighborhood of any given string-location, without relying on a top-down parser.  In this sense string literals are simpler in languages where the only complication is escape-sequences for quote marks *inside* the string, as compared to language which allow arbitrary expressions in (maybe special kinds of) strings (e.g., ${} sequences in JavaScript).

If we try to formalize this sense of some languages being more "ambiguous" than others, we might indeed find it useful to employ some notion of "context" which would be more expansive than ordinary formal grammars.  Languages that are "context free" vis-a-vis top-down parsers might have a more nuanced reliance on contexts in this alternative sense.  In short: to what extent can rules be formulated such that they can be tested against an input site irregardless of what other rules might have matched surrounding positions in the input string?

It is also true that one can perform tricks with context-free rules that entail some concept of context *de facto* even if not *de jure*.  If your grammar generates C code, for instance, you can always employ some sort of "ambient" context (maybe via global variables) which is accounted for by C code produced from a rule-match even if it is not mentioned in the rule itself.  Suppose we have a language where percent-signs have a different meaning inside string literals (cf. Qt strings with `.arg` substitution) than outside (where, say, they represent a modulo operator).  One way to model that situation is by making context explicit, have a "% inside string literals" rule which is distinct from "% outside string literals" and use contexts to activate one or the other (assume we can't just consume string literals in their entirety because of, e.g., the possibility of ${}-style embedded expressions).  However, a context-free grammar could just have a rule matching `%` signs and use the code triggered by that rule to generate different output (or otherwise behave differently) by using a C variable to indicate whether we're currently inside a string literal or not.

Technically this is still a context-free grammar because "branching" to different productions/behaviors occurs within a code body that is produced for any `%` match; the context does not factor in the rule itself.

And yet obviously some sort of context is involved here, and simply relying on the dictum that context has no formal role so long as rules themselves do not "quantify" over contexts misses what's going on in these situations.  Perhaps the best way to say it is that while grammars might be context-free, the languages *modeled* by some context-free grammars might actually be, in some substantial sense, context-sensitive.  We might want to describe a language as "context-sensitive" if the most implementationally fortuitous and conceptually meaningful grammars for the language are context-sensitive, even if it is *possible* to construct a context-free grammar which does parse the language successfully.

Again, as a case-in-point, if I were writing a compiler for a language with ${}-style expressions embedded in string literals, I would probably opt for a context-sensitive grammar so that I could switch rules on and off in contexts like embedded expressions, rather than a context-free grammar.  I would rather write one production to handle "% as a special character in string literals" and a different one for "% as a symbol for modulus" rather than merge the two into a single production with some kind of `switch` block or `if/else` branching.  The compiler code in the former case would be more meaningful and maintainable, which is a different consideration than the mathematical classification of the language in terms of its formal grammar.

Frankly, I believe context-sensitive grammars have been underappreciated and underinvestigated in formal language theory, plus compiler and software language theory.  I think computer scientists (and others) might be a little biased and think of "context free" grammars basically as just describing "formal" languages, which are systematic and unambiguous, unlike natural (human) language.  So, on this assumption, if you're working with a computationally tractable language it should have a context-free grammar by definition, and so talking about "context-free" is basically a way to signify that we're talking about formal/computer (rather than natural) language.  But that obscures the fact that formal languages can often be modeled *more systematically* via context-sensitive grammars even if it is theoretically possible to provide a context-free grammar instead.

Comment: Interesting point that sometimes it is better to choose a context-sensitive grammar even if the language can be described by a context-free grammar.

Comment: Thanks; I'm wondering if the original question was motivated by an intuition that describing languages as context-free can elide certain potentially meaningful details. For example, if a language could be described by both context-free and context-sensitive grammars, is there some way to measure which representation is more "consistent" with the language's syntax and (even) semantics? Thinking of how in "natural" linguistics -- cf cognitive grammar -- the syntax/semantics distinction is less obvious than vis-a-vis formal languages. I'm curious how to address such questions in the latter field.

Comment: I have no idea. I like the topic too, but it requires a lot more work to address these questions and currently it is only a hobby. :-)